# Unable to databind a Silverlight4 DataPager control with MVVM

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datapager

I have a data driven Silverlight 4 business application with a fairly standard user interface. There's a side section that allows you to enter your search criteria, a standard Silverlight 4 datagrid control in another section that contains your search results (if any), and then a "details" section of the screen which shows the individual information of a single row of the grid when you click on it.

Just underneath my grid control, I have placed a Silverlight DataPager control. When my datagrid has databound search results, I want the DataPager control to be activated that lets you move forwards and backwards through the dataset.

I've got the whole user interface xaml page bound to a custom viewmodel class.

My viewmodel class has a public ObservableCollection property called "Applications". I then set the xaml of my datagrid control to bind to my Applications property:

**{datagrid:DataGrid x:Name="grid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Applications}"}**

The datagrid control binds to my viewmodel with no issues. However, I'm unable to find the correct xaml syntax to bind the DataPager control to point to my same viewmodel Applications property. So the end result is my DataPager control never activates and remains disabled.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but hoping someone can send me a quick solution.

thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the xaml for the
DataPager control needed to point to my datagrid control and the binding path to
ItemsSource: